# Windows 2003 to Windows 7 Pro Classic ASP Connection String

Tags: sql, windows-7, asp-classic, connection-string

I have been searching on this topic and trying different variations for the last 3 days and can not see what I am doing wrong.

I have a site written in Classic ASP (was written long ago, just got involved, and I know nothing about Classic ASP) that calls to a SQL database. Right now it goes through an ODBC connector to connect using this snippet of code:

```vb
Dim MM_CMS_STRING
MM_CMS_STRING = "Provider=MSDASQL; Driver={SQL Native Client}; Server=lawdata02; Database=ALG; UID=user; PWD=pass"
```

I am trying to migrate them to a new server. I have setup IIS on a Windows 7 Pro machine. I have successfully moved over all the files, and migrated the SQL DB to SQL Server 2012 Express. I have installed System DSN File (SQL Server) and configured that to connect to the database. When I try to use the same connection string above, I get:

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

I have gone through so many configurations, and tried to all the debugging guides I have found around the internet and I think I am super close, but brain power is low at this point. This is what my connection string looks like now:

```vb
Dim MM_CMS_STRING
MM_CMS_STRING = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=ALG-CMS-SERVER;Initial Catalog=ALG; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80004005'
>
> TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Files and DB are all on same machine.

> IIS 7.5 | Windows 7 Pro | SQL Server Express 2012 | Classic ASP | Connection String

Comment: so the user which runs the IIS is also a valid user for the SQL Server? as you have integrated security in your cennection string the user which runs the iis/the Webpage/the pool is the user used for authentication against the sql server

Comment: If you're using SQL Server Express then shouldn't your data source be `ALG-CMS-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS`